# create symbolic link by FTP in PHP by ftp_exec function

Tags: php, ftp, symlink, execute

I want to create symbolic link on another server by FTP in PHP. but ftp_exec function in php have some limit and don't allow to do this.

Have solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can create php console command that make symlink by link function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.link.php

or exec command ln -s

Comment: Note: This function will not work on remote files as the file to be examined must be accessible via the server's filesystem.
we need to do it on another server.